# JPanel changes not showing on Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hello I'm trying to create a java game using using JPanel and JFrame. However I can't get the JPanel to show changes I make to it. I'm wondering if I might be setting up the JFrame wrong or improperly adding to it or something like that.

Here's my window class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*
public class Window extends Canvas {

public static final int ScreenWidth = 1000;
public static final int ScreenHeight = 700;
public static JFrame frame;

Window(int ScreenWidth, int ScreenHeight, JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
    displaywindow();
    frame.add(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
}

public void displaywindow() {
    this.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.frame.setResizable(false);
    this.frame.setBackground(Color.pink);
    this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return this.frame;
}
```

}

Here's the Menu class I'm working on:

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
private Window win = new Window(Window.ScreenWidth, Window.ScreenHeight, Window.frame);
private int width = Window.frame.getContentPane().getWidth();
private int height = Window.frame.getContentPane().getHeight();
BufferedImage bg;
  
Menu(JPanel panel) {
    this.panel = panel;
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.fillRect(110, 110, 20, 20);
}


public void init() throws IOException {
    this.panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    JLabel start = new JLabel("Start");
    start.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    start.setLocation(500, 400);
    this.panel.add(new JLabel("Exit"));
    this.panel.add(start);
    this.panel.revalidate();
    this.panel.repaint();
    this.panel.setVisible(true);
}

enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    Window win = new Window(Window.ScreenWidth, Window.HEIGHT, new JFrame());
    Menu mene = new Menu();
    mene.init();
    win.getFrame().getContentPane().add(mene);
    win.getFrame().setVisible(true);

}
```

I tried adding a rectangle to the paintComponent just so I was sure that the panel was actually being added to the frame and it shows that it is, but none of the changes I make in init() ever actually show. Any help would be much appreciated.

`

Comment: You never actually add menupanel to anything.  Where do you expect it to be displayed?

Comment: 1) Don't extend Canvas, that is an AWT component. With Swing you extend JPanel for custom painting. I'm not even sure why you need the "Window" class. You only extend a component when you add functionality to the component. Adding components is not adding functionality. 2) Check out [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working example of custom painting and how to use a mouse to paint a rectangle at a given location. The working examples will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: Also, components don't have a size until the frame is visible. So your statements to determine the width/height of the Menu will always be 0.

Comment: As far as modifying your menu class: to have any visual changes appear, you need to call repaint() (and sometimes revalidate())

Comment: @azurefrog doesn't getContentPane().add() add the panel to the frame?

Comment: @camickr This is the bare beginnings of my project. I want to make the window to be able to hold states, and am trying to make a state handler. I want to eventually make menu into a state the window changes to. So I figured I would try to have the panel change with each state change. Though this is my first time trying to make a gui so I'm not sure if that'll even work.

Comment: @Maya That adds the menu to the window, but you never add `menupanel` to the menu in `init()`.  No changes you make in `init()` are being displayed because you don't put anything you create there into something that is being displayed.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: @azurefrog  Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do both `class Menu extends JPanel` and declare `JPanel panel` inside of the `Menu` class. This duplication is unnecessary and causes the problem because you add items to the `panel` field, but you never do anything with that panel.

On the other hand, you declare `Menu mene` and add it to the content pane, but you never add anything to the `Menu` object itself. Don't mix and match like this. Pick a field member or inheritance, but not both.